# i have a problem with migrate on laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5.8

the error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such
>   file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where
>   table_schema = *eurofleet* and table_name = migrations and table_type =
>   'BASE TABLE')

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Note:  i am connecting to database ,i am posting and listing data , the problem is exactly on the terminal when i run the  " php artisan migrate " or any such of migration.  I am using Mac

Comment: It would be very nice to see your code so that someone can comment or add an answer.